# SQL error, I don't get it

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
INSERT INTO `tims`.`pending_profile`(`id`, `nickname`, `location`, `role`, `yog`, `interests`, `favMoment`, `gainThisYr`, `futurePlans`, `bio`) 
VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1', '', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ( nickname ='1', location= '1', role= '1',yog= '1',interests= '1',favMoment= '1',gainThisYr= '1',futurePlans= '1',bio= '1')
```

What is triggering this error?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( nickname ='1', location= '1', role= '1',yog= '1',interests= '1',favMoment= '1'' at line 3

Comment: The closing parenthesis has no matching opening parenthesis

Comment: If those numbers are really meant to be numbers, they ought not really be inside quotes either.

Comment: Thanks Ya'll    

Here's the code that worked:  

  
    INSERT INTO `tims`.`pending_profile`(`id`, `nickname`, `location`, `role`, `yog`, `interests`, `favMoment`, `gainThisYr`, `futurePlans`, `bio`) 
    VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1', '', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nickname ='1', location='1', role= '1', yog='1', interests='1', favMoment='1', gainThisYr='1', futurePlans='1', bio='1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put comma's between the fields:

```
INSERT INTO tims.pending_profile
  (id, nickname, location, role, yog, interests, favMoment, gainThisYr, futurePlans, bio) 
VALUES
  ('', '1', '1', '1', '', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nickname ='1', location= '1', role= '1', yog= '1', interests= '1', favMoment= '1', gainThisYr= '1', futurePlans= '1', bio= '1'
```

Comment: The closing parenthesis has no matching opening parenthesis.

Comment: +1: Yes, the query is missing the commas between the fields in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: @TP: True, that will turn up as another 1064 error *after* the commas are added, so I addressed it when I edited the answer for formatting.

Comment: Finally got the formatting right :) shouldn't you use NULL instead of '' on id?

Answer (score 1):

You never opened your parentheses and you need commas between the fields

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE **(**nickname ='1', location= '1', role= '1', yog= '1', interests= '1', favMoment= '1', gainThisYr= '1', futurePlans= '1', bio= '1')
```

Comment: The brackets aren't necessary, per the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

Should you not use commas to separate your list of columns to update on the last line?